# OpenCV reinstallation problems

Tags: opencv, cmake

I installed OpenCV 2.4.12 a while ago, and about 2 days ago installed OpenCV 3.2. Immediately after I went through the installation procedure ([this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/OpenCV-3.2-Installation-Guide-on-Ubuntu-16.04) is the guide I followed), my old openCV code would keep telling me that it couldn't find the cv functions when I tried to compile it. Clearly a linker error. Later I realized that I was supposed to be working with the 2.4 version instead, so I deleted my opencv-3.2.0 folder in my home directory and ran sudo make install in my 2.4.12 folder again. This seemed to work, but again the cv functions could not be found.

So here's what I have found by myself so far.

I printed out some of the variables in my CMakeLists.txt, and my OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS points to /usr/include/opencv/usr/include, which is obviously the problem. But now how do I fix it? I tried setting that variable manually using this line

set( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include/opencv/)

but again, to no avail.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
set( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include/opencv/)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "CMAKE_ROOT: " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp)
SET(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc)
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "CMAKE_ROOT: " ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

And here is the CMake configuration I used.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_CUBLAS=ON -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Finally, here is my config [file](https://gist.github.com/Riteshlogin/687c39f7778b59f8594d528afdd15302).

EDIT: Also, if I run
     gcc analyze_video.cpp -o objDetection -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_highgui

Then everything works. So I have the libraries built, but something is wrong with my CMake configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` is a list. In CMake, `message(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})` will print each list element without any delimiters in between. Moreover `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` is a path to headers, not to a library. Linkage errors occur when a function is defined (i.e. headers are found) but symbols are not (i.e. a required library is not linked).

Please clarify your problem by updating your question to include the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` file from your project, CMake configuration flags that used for OpenCV build, or provide a link to GitHub Gists, etc. if it is too large. The more information you provide, the faster someone can help you.

Comment: Ah ha, I thought that a double installation had appended the include path and therefore the include path became invalid. Which folder would I likely find the binaries in? And why would the INCLUDE_DIRS variable ever point to the base of the include directory?

Comment: @Tri, let me just provide you my way to build a minimal application with OpenCV:
OpenCV build:
`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE .. && make -j4 && sudo make install`.
App's CMakeLists has only two lines contains OpenCV: `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` `target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})`.
And no FindOpenCV.cmake or something else is require.
I would like if you could reproduce it by yourself. Here is my working script if I want to build certain OpenCV modules: goo.gl/p1snyO. But be careful, check what require modules for you are enabled.

Comment: Ok, I will definitely try that! And I upvoted your original answer, but you can't see it because I don't have enough points.

Comment: It started working after I copied a file called "FindOpenCV.cmake" from OpenCV's github and put that in my directory. I'm still not absolutely sure that pasting that file in did the trick, but I'll take it I guess? Not knowing the true cause of this problem is going to haunt me. Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer because there is no other answer to accept and this problem is solved.

Comment: I did two other things between an instance of the build not working and the build working- I changed a #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" to #include "opencv/opencv.hpp" and then I changed it back, and I ran the gcc command as I described in the above post. But for whatever reason, the gcc command doesn't work. But I don't care enough to figure out why that isn't working.

Comment: @Tri, problem is solved? If not, could you create a temporal repository with your CMakeLists and some usage to test OpenCV is linked correctly?

Comment: Yeah, when I run CMake everything behaves the way it is supposed to now. How can I test if opencv is linked correctly? That was my problem the entire time.